# Dynamic bootstrap modal. 3 button 1 modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

i want to Single modal trigger with multiple buttons.

my buttons;

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-primary" type="button" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">Button 1</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-primary" type="button" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">Button 2</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-primary" type="button" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">Button 3</button>
```

Just i want to add variable. example; ?link=1

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-primary?link=1" type="button" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">Button 1</button>
```

i ask this cause in modal i have a form, hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is simple example shown three button trigger single Modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <!-- first -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button 1</button>
 <!-- sec --> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button 2</button>

<!-- third -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button 3</button>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```